# Same pojo object for 2 different XML tags

Tags: xml, jaxb

I have two xmls like this. One is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
<VersNbr>1</VersNbr>
<SubmrId>ABC</SubmrId>
<MsgSeqNbr>00065</MsgSeqNbr>
<CreateDt>20180528</CreateDt>
<CreateTm>172428</CreateTm>
<TravelBatch>
<BtchSeqNbr>00000001</BtchSeqNbr>
<ProviderNm>Travel</ProviderNm>
<TrvlBtchCurrCd>GBP</TrvlBtchCurrCd>
</TravelBatch>
</Message>
```

and  second is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
<VersNbr>2</VersNbr>
<SubmrId>Xyz</SubmrId>
<MsgSeqNbr>000460</MsgSeqNbr>
<CreateDt>20180528</CreateDt>
<CreateTm>172428</CreateTm>
<RefBatch>
<BtchSeqNbr>00000001</BtchSeqNbr>
<ProviderNm> Travel</ProviderNm>
<TrvlBtchCurrCd>GBP</TrvlBtchCurrCd>
</RefBatch>
</Message>
```

My pojo is

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message {

@XmlElement(name = "VersNbr")
protected int versNbr;
@XmlElement(name = "SubmrId")
protected String submrId;
@XmlElement(name = "MktCode")
protected String mktCode;
@XmlElement(name = "FileStatus")
protected String fileStatus;
@XmlElement(name = "MsgSeqNbr")
protected String msgSeqNbr;
@XmlElement(name = "CreateDt")
protected String createDt;
@XmlElement(name = "CreateTm")
protected String createTm;
@XmlElement(name = "ExprDt")
protected String exprDt;
@XmlElement(name = "HubTimeStamp")
protected String hubTimeStamp;
protected List<TravelBatch> travelBatch;
@XmlElement(name = "SettleBatch")
protected List<SettleBatch> settleBatch;
@XmlElement(name = "MessageTrailer", required = true)
protected MessageTrailer messageTrailer;
protected String isValidRec;

//getters and setters
```

Can we handle both TravelBatch and RefBatch tags with same tarvelBatch object?
I tried using @XmlElements by giving 2 seperate @XMLElement but its not working as expected.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that seems different in the xmls is the surrounding element for some batch details. So you could create a new class like below:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class BatchDetails {

    @XmlElement(name = "BtchSeqNbr")
    private String batchSequenceNumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "ProviderNm")
    private String providerName;
    @XmlElement(name = "TrvlBtchCurrCd")
    private String travelBatchCurrencyCode;
}
```

And then your root class, in order to handle both xmls would look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Message")
public class Message {

    @XmlElement(name = "VersNbr")
    protected int versNbr;
    @XmlElement(name = "SubmrId")
    protected String submrId;
    @XmlElement(name = "MktCode")
    protected String mktCode;
    @XmlElement(name = "FileStatus")
    protected String fileStatus;
    @XmlElement(name = "MsgSeqNbr")
    protected String msgSeqNbr;
    @XmlElement(name = "CreateDt")
    protected String createDt;
    @XmlElement(name = "CreateTm")
    protected String createTm;
    @XmlElement(name = "ExprDt")
    protected String exprDt;
    @XmlElement(name = "HubTimeStamp")
    protected String hubTimeStamp;

    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "RefBatch", type = BatchDetails.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "TravelBatch", type = BatchDetails.class)
    })
    protected BatchDetails batchDetails;

    protected String isValidRec;
}
```

Note the batchDetails field with the `@XmlElements` annotation.